# Sharing data between tabs

Tags: android

I am getting some glitches while making a tab enabled application.
I want to share data, between two tabs of my application.
How can I achieve the same?

Rgds
Robert

Answer (score 13, accepted):

the correct way is setting a static field into the activity that creates the tabs

```
 public class greformanews extends TabActivity {

       public static String JorgesysTitle;
...
...
...
```

so in your Activity defined in tab 1

```
 @Override
 protected void onPause() { 
    greformanews.JorgesysTitle = "JORGESYS =)";
 super.onPause();
}
```

in your Activity defined in tab 2

```
//get  value defined in Activity 1 !:)
String Title =  greformanews.JorgesysTitle
```

Comment: greformanews is not visible in my activity in tab1 ?
How can I access it?

Comment: it is public. Do I have to import the class? when I put greformanews. It goes with the red wigly line and can't find any member...

Comment: Still not working. If I do, gamesmodestab help=new gamesmodestab(); it works fine.
However this will declare a new instance of it. Accessing the parent instance by gamesmodestab.life gives the wigly line and an error.

Comment: what is the exception paste de stacktrace!

Comment: you can see the exception in the "Problems" tab in your eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use intents to different activities, or in that case of tabs.

Go to [Android Common Tasks](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#opennewscreen)

And look at the subject below "some intent examples". This will get you started.

You basically need to put whatever values you want into a bundle and pass that over to the new activity using intent.putextras();

Comment: very diferent to share data between activities defined into tabs.