# Android - send string between activities

Tags: android, webview, android-activity

im having trouble getting a string (containing a URL) from one activity to another.
I've tried using intent but that didn't work.

I've got a main activity setting up the tabhost with tabs.
There are 3 tabs, one with a barcode scanner, one with a search field and a webview.

The barcode scanner and search field create a string containing a Url i want the webview to show.

Could someone please tell me I'm missing something or how i could do this better?

My main activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setTabs() ;
}
private void setTabs()
{
    addTab("Home", R.drawable.tab_home, HomeActivity.class);
    addTab("Search", R.drawable.tab_search, SearchActivity.class);
    addTab("Play", R.drawable.tab_favorite, FavoriteActivity.class);
}

private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
{
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId); 

    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(labelId);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
}

public void switchTab(int tab){
    TabHost tabHost1 = getTabHost();
    tabHost1.setCurrentTab(tab);
}
```

The webview tab

```
public class WebviewActivity extends Activity {
WebView webView;
String url;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.favoritepage);

    url = "http://www.google.nl";

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
    webView.loadUrl(url);

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    webView.saveState(outState);
 }
}
```

and the search tab

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button searchButton;
TextView searchText;
TextView searchResultText;
String zoekopdracht, completeTrailerUrl, searchUrl;
String baseURL = "http://not_needed_here";
String endURL = "End_of_url";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.searchpage);

    searchText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.searchText);
    searchResultText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.searchResultText);

    searchButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
    searchButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View buttonId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (buttonId.getId()){
    case R.id.searchButton :
        zoekopdracht = searchText.getText().toString();

        StringBuilder completeURL = new StringBuilder(baseURL);
        completeURL.append(zoekopdracht + endURL);
        searchUrl = completeURL.toString();

        /**start de thread om de xml zoekopdracht te doen */
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL website = new URL(searchUrl);

                    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                    XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

                    HandlingXMLStuff doingWork = new HandlingXMLStuff();
                    xr.setContentHandler(doingWork);
                    InputSource is=new InputSource(website.openStream());
                    xr.parse(is);

                    completeTrailerUrl = doingWork.getInformation();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
          }).start();
        searchResultText.setText(completeTrailerUrl);
        //I want completeTrailerUrl to be loaded in the webview
        break;
    }
}
}
```

#### In reaction to Barrel

I've changed the receiving class into this, but i think this is where i'm going wrong.

```
public class FavoriteActivity extends Activity {
WebView webView;
String url;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.favoritepage);

    // part submitted by Cool Compiler
    Intent t=getIntent();
    Bundle k = t.getExtras();
    url=k.getString("stringToPassOn");

    if (url != null){
        url = "http://www.google.nl";


    }

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
    webView.loadUrl(url);

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    webView.saveState(outState);
 }
}
```

when running this, the webview is all black and on rotate it crashes

```
06-22 13:32:45.380: W/dalvikvm(1630): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a51228)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.georgekroon.player/com.georgekroon.player.TUplayerV2Activity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.georgekroon.player/com.georgekroon.player.FavoriteActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3505)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3585)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3783)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1266)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5005)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.georgekroon.player/com.georgekroon.player.FavoriteActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2202)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1992)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.dispatchStop(LocalActivityManager.java:579)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at android.app.ActivityGroup.onStop(ActivityGroup.java:82)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1266)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:4706)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3500)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     ... 12 more
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at com.georgekroon.player.FavoriteActivity.onCreate(FavoriteActivity.java:25)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4543)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2158)
06-22 13:32:45.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1630):     ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Bundle.

In your activity add something like

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle ();
bundle.putSerializable("stringToPassOn", YOUR_STRING);

Intent xxx;
xxx.putExtras (bundle);
startActivityForResult (xxx, 0);
```

And you retrieve the information later on via:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String myText = (String) bundle.getSerializable ("stringToPassOn");
```

Comment: I've tried that, but the webview does not seem to respond to it

Comment: This answer is found in some other allmost similar problems and I did try this first.

The webview remains a black screen (not even white) and crashes on rotation

Comment: The first part is done just before you call a new activity. I.e. you click on a button, you create the intent, put the bundle on it and then and start the new intent. In the 'onCreate' of the new intent, you can then retrieve the information by the second part of the code examples. Is this what you have done? Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: I think the problem is that i got the second (receiving part) in the onCreate part..

It should be receiving it just when it is submitted, not just onCreate, putting something together now and will submit it again

Comment: Line 25 of your FavoritAction, which line is it? Your check on whether the URL != null is incorrect, it should be 'if (url == null)'. In your code the URL will be overwritten if it already has a value. If it is null, it remains null. Might this be the cause of the Nullpointer?

Comment: indeed, good one.. but not THE one screen is still black and crash on rotate (null pointer)

Comment: at com.georgekroon.player.FavoriteActivity.onCreate(FavoriteActivity.java:25) Which one is line 25? What exactly does it say?

Comment: line 25 says         url=k.getString("stringToPassOn");

line 27 is if (url == null){

Comment: If think you initiiate the activity in an incorrect way. The forementioned code works if you start the activity by creating the intent and then start the activity with this intent (startActivityForResult (your_intent, 0)). I have added this line to the code example

Comment: but the activity is initially started by the tabhost, so that is why that activity crashes right?

Comment: Indeed. Check this link for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221940/using-bundle-and-intent-with-tabhost

Answer (score 0):

you need to use bundles.. and it must work fine then. eg.;

```
                     s=new Intent(Format1.this, Format17.class);
                    d=new Bundle();
                    d.putString("userId", userId);
                    d.putString("surveyId", surveyId);
                    d.putInt("quesNo", ques_no);
                    s.putExtras(d);
                    startActivity(s);
```

now in next class you can retrieve values like this

```
Intent t=getIntent();
    Bundle k=t.getExtras();
    surveyId=k.getString("surveyId");
    userId=k.getString("userId");
    ques_no=k.getInt("quesNo");
```

Try this....

Comment: sorry, but what are the Format1 and Format17 pointing to?
besides, this looks like the answer "barrel" gave

Comment: format1 is the name of the current activity and format17 is the name of next activity where you want to send the string. in your case instead of format17 u will write WebviewActivity.