# How to pass parameters to other tabs (Android)

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sharing data between tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300695/sharing-data-between-tabs)

In the main Tab, I have a button. After clicking it, it calls tabHost.setCurrentTab(1)
It then goes to another tab. But here, I want to pass the value of editText in Tab(0) to Tab(1). How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

**Tab 0**

```
getParent().getIntent().putExtra("key", "value");
```

**Tab 1**

```
String value = getParent().getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```