# Handling dependent data between tabs in tabbed activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I'm currently trying to switch my Android application from individual activities to fragments contained in a single tabbed activity, however, I'm running into some snags with figuring out how to pass data between them. I was originally just using intents. However, now that I'm using fragments, I'm currently storing any data I need as a field variable in my tabbed activity (As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301533/2864464) answer outlines). I'm getting null pointer exceptions because my tabbed activity is attempting to load my first *and* second fragment, but **my second fragment depends on a EditText value from my first fragment**. Is there any way I can load these fragments one at a time, and pass my field data (and load my second fragment) when the user swipes? If there is a way, is this the best way of solving my problem? I'm very open to other suggestions. Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special dedicated topic for this here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html.

I would declare two interface one in each fragment. Then implement the interface in the activity. On `EditText` change in the first fragment send the value to the activity and store the value in the activity in a instance variable. Then on the second fragment retrieve the value in the second activity from the activity.

Comment: Great, I think this will work! I'll accept if I can fix one other small concern I have: is there any way to disable swiping _until_ that EditText is filled?

Comment: i can think of this..  override the page change listeners. If the edittext is not filled, program it to swipe back to the first fragment.

Comment: Sorry I never got back to you! That worked perfectly with a little bit of gymnastics with my viewpager. Thank you:)